# Activating search bar doesn't hide navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uisearchbar

I have an iOS 7 application in XCode 5.0 that exhibits some strange behavior when tapping the search bar (`UISearchBar`).

My application has a Navigation Controller, and a Tab Bar Controller. Here is an example of what my Main.Storyboard looks like:

```
[Navigation Controller] -> [Tab Bar Controller] -> [Tab Item #1]
                                    |
                                    -------------> [Tab Item #2]

Each [] is a view controller
```

When I launch my application, I see the `Tab Item 1` with the `UISearchBar` as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: one]

When I tap the `UISearchBar`, the search bar slides up to the top of the screen, but the Navigation Bar does not hide, and the view does not "slide up". This causes the app to look like this:

[image: two]

When I delete the `Tab Bar Controller` from the storyboard and connect the `Navigation Controller` directly to `Tab Item #1` the Navigation Bar hides as expected.

How can I make the Navigation Bar hide when tapping the Search Bar? For an example of the functionality I am looking to reproduce, click the search bar under the "Contacts" tab of the default iOS7 "Phone" application.

Comment: Do you really want the navigation controller to contain the tab bar controller? Generally it's the other way around.

Comment: @nevanking - I had tried to do it the other way and I couldn't get it to work. The Navigation bar should span the entire application, not just the `Tab Item #1` view. What is the reasoning for switching the other way around?

Comment: It's just the more normal way to do it. Look at the Music app or the Clock app. You might think about giving each tab it's own navigation controller which then contains the content view controller.

Answer (score 5):

For **swift** developers:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { 

  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { 

  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

}
```

This will hide the navigation bar while search bar is active and show it again when search bar is inactive.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the UISearchBar delegate methods to decide when to move the navigationbar out of the screen.

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        double yDiff = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - statusBarFrame.size.height;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, yDiff, 320, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
    }];

}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        double yDiff = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + statusBarFrame.size.height;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, yDiff, 320, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

Comment: How can I do that in swift?

Answer (score 4):

The following line will hide the navigation bar animatedly on activating search bar.

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the top bar in the navigation controller for the list, to none and then add this to your tabBarController code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent= NO;
```

In the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with UISearchDisplayController method;

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(mySearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    self.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
    {
        CGRect statusBarFrame =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01 animations:^{
            for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews)
                subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, statusBarFrame.size.height);
        }];
    }
}

-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(mySearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01 animations:^{
            for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews)
                subview.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }
}
```

Don't forget create a new class as a type of UISearchDisplayController and implement that code in it.

Comment: Also you should wanna see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932192/issue-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview-in-ios7/20091672#20091672

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding constraint on Search Bar to Top Layout Guide and set its value to 0 and added a vertical spacing constraint to Search Bar and setting its value to 0;

Answer (score -1):

I realize that this is probably too late to help you, but I ran into the same issue today!

I solved it by fixing the constraints of the search bar. Make sure the search bar has a constraint of 0px for its immediate top neighbor (the nav bar). Also make sure the tableview below the search bar has a constraint of 0px for its immediate top neighbor (the search bar).

Not sure of the exact problem you were facing, but that fixed it for me.